# Space before reply causes reply to not render

Tags: bug, chat

While typing a chat message that was a reply, I accidentally put a space before the colon marking the reply. I didn’t bother to delete it, as I figured chat would trim the message for me. Instead, the reply failed to render. At first it looked like a ping with no reply arrow, but after reloading the page it shows the raw text:

[image]

(Screenshot from iOS 17.1, but I can reproduce it in Firefox 119 on Windows 11.)

Comment: Well yes that's a weird bug, but why would you manually write the reply (i.e. colon followed by message id) instead of just clicking the reply arrow? (button in mobile view.)

Comment: I didn’t; I did click the reply button. On iOS you can move your cursor with the spacebar and so I accidentally added an extra space at the beginning when trying to move my cursor.

Comment: Well fix **should** be indeed a trivial `.trim();` on the input in the server side code handling the message, but... well... sadly that doesn't mean much. (i.e. can't expect the bug to be fixed faster because it's an easy fix)

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry It isn’t that simple, is it? Four spaces makes it a code block.

Comment: The real bug is how the ping renders inconsistently depending on if you where in the chatroom at the time or looking back. Arguably a reply should *not* count if a space comes before it, but right now the message sometimes displays as a ping and sometimes as raw text

Comment: @mousetail the client side code handles it as reply, but after reload the actual message is being displayed, yeah.

Comment: I should add that, even when it does render as a ping, it still doesn’t actually ping you. There’s no sound and the text isn’t highlighted.